# Format Long Strings in Manifest

Tags: java

I'm in the process for creating an Eclipse plug-in that manipulates the *Manifest.MF* of projects. However the format is not how I like it.

Consider the following code:

```
    final String[] bundles = { "org.acme.alpha", "org.acme.beta", "org.acme.gamma", "org.acme.delta", "org.acme.epsilon", "org.acme.zeta", "org.acme.eta", "org.acme.theta", "org.acme.iota", "org.acme.kappa", "org.acme.lambda" };

    try (ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("Manifest-Version: 1.0\n\n".getBytes())) {
        Manifest manifest = new Manifest(in);
        manifest.getMainAttributes().putValue("Require-Bundle", Arrays.stream(bundles).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
        manifest.write(System.out);
    }
```

The relevant output is then:

```
Require-Bundle: org.acme.alpha,org.acme.beta,org.acme.gamma,org.acme.del
 ta,org.acme.epsilon,org.acme.zeta,org.acme.eta,org.acme.theta,org.acme.
 iota,org.acme.kappa,org.acme.lambda
```

Which looks incredible ugly, especially if you add `bundle-versions` into the mix. I'd rather have one line per bundle.

The naive approach is to just add a line break myself, so the *Manifest.MF* doesn't need to break every 72 chars. So I added `Arrays.stream(bundles).collect(Collectors.joining(",\n "))`. The result is:

```
Require-Bundle: org.acme.alpha,
 org.acme.beta,
 org.acme.gamma,
 org.acme.
  delta,
 org.acme.epsilon,
 org.acme.zeta,
 org.acme.eta,
 org.acme.theta,
 o
  rg.acme.iota,
 org.acme.kappa,
 org.acme.lambda
```

Which looks almost correct, except... there is still an additional line break every 72 characters, only a bit less visible.

Is there any way to format long strings in manifest files any other way than as a block? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: I know of no way to get control of that other than by writing the file yourself rather than providing Java with the key/values to set. Note, however, that this file uses mime-format. A simple end of line is not correct, as how exactly do you distinguish between the continuation of "Require-Bundle" or the next property? You need a newline, followed by a space.

Comment: @kumesana Yes, you are completely right. The space got somehow lost while copying my example.